# Problems in NP but not in Average-P/poly

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np, conditional-results, advice-and-nonuniformity, average-case-complexity

The [Karp–Lipton Theoem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp-Lipton_theorem) states that if $\mathsf{NP} \subset \mathsf{P/poly}$, then $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses to $\mathsf{\Sigma^P_2}$. Therefore, assuming separations between $\mathsf{\Sigma^P_2}$ and $\mathsf{\Sigma^P_3}$, no $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem will belong to $\mathsf{P/poly}$.

I'm interested in the following question:

> Assuming that $\mathsf{PH}$ does not collapse, or assuming any other reasonable assumption in structural complexity, what **hard-on-average** $\mathsf{NP}$ problems are *proven* not to lie in $\mathsf{Average\mbox{-}P/poly}$ (if any)?

A definition of $\mathsf{Average\mbox{-}P/poly}$ can be found in [Relations between Average-case and Worst-case Complexity](http://www.cse.unl.edu/~vinod/papers/fct05.ps). Thanks to Tsuyoshi for pointing out that I actually need to use $\mathsf{Average\mbox{-}P/poly}$ instead of $\mathsf{P/poly}$.

I *think* there are problems such as (the decision versions of) [FACTORING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) or [DLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) which are conjectured to lie in $\mathsf{NP} - \mathsf{Average\mbox{-}P/poly}$, but the conjecture is not proven based on separations between complexity classes. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: (1) I do not think that the assumption that the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse is known to imply that there is a hard-on-average problem in NP.  Section 18.4 of Arora and Barak states: “[…] even though we know that if P=NP, then the polynomial hierarchy PH collapses to P […], we don’t have an analogous result for average case complexity.”

Comment: (2) Is P/poly in the question the usual one with worst-case complexity, or are you considering an average-case analogue of it?  If it is the worst-case one, then you need both DistP≠DistNP and NP⊈P/poly to have such a problem, and if these hold, then every DistNP-complete problem satisfies the requirement because a DistNP-complete problem is necessarily NP-complete if we throw away the input distribution.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thanks a lot. You do have a point about the worst-case vs. average-case P/poly. On a second thought (about the original problem), I think I have to interpret P/poly as an **average-case** class.

Comment: I read the revision 3.  Tautologically, such a problem exists if and only if DistNP ⊈ Average-P/poly.  And if DistNP ⊈ Average-P/poly, then every DistNP-complete problem lies outside Average-P/poly because Average-P/poly is closed under reductions (between distributional problems).  But maybe you are asking for a more natural problem under a stronger assumption.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thank you. Could you make the comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Sadeq: Done. -

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a slightly improved version of my two comments on the question combined.

Let’s restrict our attention to distributional problems in [DistNP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aD#distnp) (aka (NP, P-computable)) for simplicity.  Then you are looking for a problem in DistNP ∖ Average-P/poly.  Tautologically, such a problem exists if and only if DistNP ⊈ Average-P/poly.  And if DistNP ⊈ Average-P/poly, then every DistNP-complete problem lies outside Average-P/poly because Average-P/poly is closed under average-case reductions.

(Considering a larger class SampNP (aka [(NP, P-samplable)](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aN#nppsamp)) instead of DistNP does not change the situation much because DistNP ⊆ Average-P/poly if and only if SampNP ⊆ Average-P/poly.  This equivalence is a direct corollary of the result by Impagliazzo and Levin [IL90] that every distributional problem in SampNP is average-case reducible to some distributional problem in DistNP.)

I do not know which natural assumption implies DistNP ⊈ Average-P/poly.  The assumption that the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse is not known to imply even a weaker consequence that DistNP ⊈ Average-P, according to Section 18.4 of Arora and Barak [AB09]: “[…] even though we know that if P=NP, then the polynomial hierarchy PH collapses to P […], we don’t have an analogous result for average case complexity.”

#### References

[AB09] Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak.  *Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach*, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

[IL90] Russell Impagliazzo and Leonid A. Levin.  No better ways to generate hard NP instances than picking uniformly at random.  In *the 31st Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science*, 812–821, Oct. 1990.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/FSCS.1990.89604